# Are there any tactics or tools for matching synergis or is it just skill?

Tags: hearthstone

When I'm playing recomended tierlists decks, while playing I even can see synergize in my hand without knowing (due to lack of time for reading descriptions) what the deck is about. When I'm trying to design my own decks and play them it more feels like a typical arena run. (Even when I had while designing the deck a lot of overlapping synergize of the cards I used in mind).

Of course creating a tier 1 deck is something a lot of ingenuity and knowledge is required for. But my own decks almost in 75% of my matches result in locking down my own hand with dead cards.

So I want to have a good start when the new card series arrives (thankfully most cards that got nerfed I ahve multiple golden copys of so getting the new cards will be easy one).

But since it takes some days before the new meta is getting visible and the first decks go to be published in the internet, I want to create 1 or 2 own reliable decks.

So what techniques/tools can I use to craft a reliable, strong and synergizing deck with as few potential dead cards as possible?

Or is it just about affinity to the traits and the math behind it and there are just people who cope with it and those who dont?

Comment: I think it is a mix of skill together with trial and error. Just thinking of what might work testing it out, seeing that it either works or it doesn't. Then remove the things that don't work/keep those that work. And try again... So loads of iterations of the same deck with small differences until you find one that works. Don't think you are going to make the best deck on your first try.

Comment: @Lyrion: So people who make with new card sets the meta on the first day are just lucky that they came to a working state so fast? But even in that case I guess there could be some thumb rules.

Comment: Well it depends, now with the old gods for example you can see some synergy with the cards that give +/+ to c'thun and c'thun himself. As with cards that trigger off c'thun like the ancient shieldbearer. Some people are probably already thinking about decks they could build. But no one knows for sure if the decks will actually work, that is where the iteration comes in. If you look at Trumps midrange hunter deck for example he is at version 4.1 already. After playing a few matches and noticing the dead cards you remove them and try adding something else that might work.

Answer (score 7):

If you take a look at how popular players/deck creators work, it's a combination of intuition about deck synergies and a trial and error process that progress through subsequent refinements.

Take for example [Anyfin Can Happen](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/27240-anyfin-can-happen): it's clearly designed to belong in a combo deck, with its high cost and high board impact. So you start from this idea and try to build the deck around it.

One of the first thing you have to ask is: "What is my ***win condition***?"; what is the mechanism that gives you victory? It can be a specific combo or even just a simple "get board control and smash the opponent's face". Usually you try to get a win condition that fits the class you're building: if you try to make a Shaman fatigue deck, you're going to have a hard time, while for a Warrior deck it may be more manageable. Figuring out a good/original win condition is usually one of the hardest parts of creating a new deck, and requires a good dose of skill, creativity and understanding of the current metagame: this is because you have to clearly have in mind how the class you chose works and you should also know how the *cards* in that class work.

Once you have a clear win condition you have to ask yourself: "How can I achieve that?" Here comes the trial and error part: now you'll have to actually build your deck and test it through dozens of matches to verify that the synergies you're putting in actually work. Take for example the aforementioned Anyfin Can Happen: once you put that card as your win condition, you set your deck on a path that requires card draw (or else you risk not finding the card), self heal (you have to survive until turn 10, or later), board clears (to avoid being overwhelmed by the opponent's board) and the right amount of murlocs in your deck (a board full of [Murloc raiders](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/55-murloc-raider) on turn 10 is going to be useless).

The first iterations of Anyfin paladin were clunky because were including too many murlocs or were lacking good ways to clear the board. Once people started including [Doomsayers](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/467-doomsayer), [Pyro](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/25-wild-pyromancer)+[Equality](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/383-equality), [Lay on hands](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/506-lay-on-hands), and, most importantly, reduced the murloc presence to just Bluegills, Warleaders and Old Murk-Eye, the deck finally found its definitive (and fearsome) incarnation.

Naturally this is just an example, but the thought process usually is similar. It takes creativity to come out with a new deck archetype, but it also takes a lot of work to make it actually ladder-viable.

One final note: if in 75% of the cases you lock your hand with dead cards you may have to reevaluate both your deckbuilding process AND your game plan. The whole deck needs to progress your match towards your win condition, but also it's important the way you play it. The mulligan at the beginning may be the difference between a glorious victory and a catastrophic loss. You can't keep in your hand the same cards against an Aggro Shaman or a Control Warrior, but the only way to become good at this is actually knowing what you're facing. You have to understand the meta, calculate the chances that the player you're facing is, for example, a Face or a Midrange Hunter and change your game plan accordingly.

Since you mentioned creating reliable decks let me give you another advice: don't craft or disenchant any card until the new expansion becomes available. Whispers of the Old Gods, as you probably already know, is going to introduce new cards, while restricting many others to the Wild game mode only. The meta will shift a lot and decks considered solid or at least playable today may not be viable at all when the patch hits on April 26th (27th for Europe and Asia). If you have the cards already available, play with them, otherwise don't craft any new one for the moment. If you want to "have a good start", ***wait***. New strong decks are going to rise, creating one today will not help you in a week.

Comment: This was allready a big help. I have a blessing whats curse in same. I had for several months big luck like drawing 1 leg all 5 boosters. So having allmost all cards available made me not asking for "whats my win condition?" but "What makes me looking fancy?" I never even had that idea of setting a win condition. What I'm now curious about: What would be the win condition resulting in a face hunter-like deck?

Comment: @Zaibis the win condition for a face deck (all of them, not exclusively hunter) is to reduce the opponents life to 0 before being overwhelmed by the opponent, simple as that. They usually do that using cheap minions with high damage potential and high burst spells. Anyway this moment is probably the worst to craft cards for your decks, especially for face hunter: with the new expansion many cards are becoming restricted to a single game mode, Wild, while new are being introduced. I'll update the answer to address this concern too.

Comment: There is actually no reason for me to craft cards now, since I have all cards except some useless legs and own 8k dust in backhand :D Aswell, I'm aware of the incomming changes for card restrictions and changes. Thanks anyways. Your everyfin example did sound that by wincondition it is meant to be a card. Now undr this view.... isn't reducing the opponents health to 0 or below, the win condition of any deck? Under this view I'm curious how saying "ok I have to reduce my enemys life to 0" gets me any further in crafting a deck.

Comment: @Zaibis for face decks the speed is fundamental, they simply rush everything they have and do damage as fast as possible. Yes, the ultimate goal is always reducing the opponent to 0, but there are various ways to do that. If you want we can continue this discussion on battle.net, you can find my tag on my profile: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/23609/kappei?tab=profile

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a general knowledge about card effects and interplay I can only see two "tools" that help build a synergizing deck:

1. Curve - How much mana will be available to you, is one of the few (almost) fixed values of the game. As such you can predict how much cards of each mana level you will need. Roughly: The cheaper a card is, the more chances you will have to play, the more often it should be included in your deck.
2. Purpose - As you design your deck, allready have a number of plays and counterplays in mind. Now you can gear the rest of your deck arround giving you opportunities to put those combos into use. The easier it is to play a combo, the better the deck will operate.